# Admin notification email failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send an email to administrator from the *production environment*, but failing to... It *works in development* with [**`letter opener gem`**](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener), but when I try in production, I'm getting the following error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at app/controllers/contact_us_controller.rb:8:in `submit_form'
app/models/contact_form.rb:13:in `send_admin_notification'
```

My code for the **submit_form action in the controller** is:

```
def submit_form
  @contact_form.attributes = contact_form_params
  return redirect_to action: :thanks if @contact_form.save

  render :index
end
```

and the code in the **contact_form model** is:

```
def send_admin_notification
  AdminNotifier.contact_form(self).deliver_now
end
```

I've been struggling with this for the past 2 days so any help and guidance would much much appreciated

Comment: Have you configured the SMTP settings for production? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-mailer

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me on the production env:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'gmail.com',
    :user_name            => 'koshlendra@gmail.com',
    :password             => 'secret_password',
    :authentication       => 'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these configurations in your production.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'yourhost'}
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
   config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
       :port => 587,
       :domain => 'gmail.com',
       :user_name => "your email",
       :password => "yourpassword",
       :authentication => :plain,
       :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
```